# Make Div Smallest Possible Width

Tags: javascript, html, css

The Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GosuWhite/sXgAY/

You input numbers separated by any characters and it calculates some summary statistics. The summary statistics are output in area designated for the calculator in this divs:

```
<div id="solWrap">
    <div id="solTitles"></div>
    <div id="solStats"></div>
</div>
```

So You'd basically have something like this:

```
Sample Variance:    12.212
Population Variace: 12.291
```

I wanted to essentially center these statistics in the calculator area, but I don't know the width, so I used this:

```
solWrap.offsetWidth = outputTitles.offsetWidth + outputStats.offsetWidth + "px";
```

Cool, should work right? It turns out it doesn't and that's because outputStats is HIGHLY greedy and uses more width than it needs, and in fact, it actually uses all the remaining width available.

What can I do? Don't throw Jquery at me. Libraries are nice but I prefer sweet, sweet vanilla.

Edit: This is what I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKptU.jpg
I want that effect, but that was achieved through actually literally setting the width of the solWrap div. Since this calculator is dynamic, I want the width dynamically generated.

New Edit: No one has answered correctly yet.

Here is what is going on:

JavaScript is generating content inside two divs:

```
Sample Variance:    12.212
Population Variace: 12.291
```

Div 1 will contain "Sample Variance 
 Populati..."

And the other div will contain the data.

These are inside of the calculator text area which has a width of 400px and are both being displayed as inline-blocks.

The thing is when JavaScript generates this content inside of the divs, it does it corrently for the "sample variance...". It sets the width to the smallest possible value it can have.

But when JavaScript generates the content inside the div for the numbers, it sets the width way bigger than it needs to be and in fact takes up the rest of the area inside the calculator div.

How can I force the div that contains the numbers to be as small as it can?]

**SOLUTION:** I found a solution. Instead of display: inline-block, I used display: table and set the inner divs to display:table cell and it worked.

Comment: so you just wanna center content in a div right ? why not css ?

Comment: No, I want the div centered not the actual content. Everything is generated after an event.

Comment: do you want the div to be resized ?

Comment: Added an edit to make what I want clearer

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center a div in a div - horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally)

Comment: Added edit since no one gets it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f2ZsE/)

**html**

```
<form id="calcForm">
    <div id="outercalcTextArea">
        <div id="calcTextArea" contenteditable="true">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="calcButton"><center><button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button></center></div>
</form>
```

**css**

```
#outercalcTextArea{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF; 
    border: 1px solid #C9C9C9; 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset, -5px -5px 0 0 #F5F5F6, 5px 5px 0 0 #F5F5F6, 5px 0 0 0 #F5F5F6, 0 5px 0 0 #F5F5F6, 5px -5px 0 0 #F5F5F6, -5px 5px 0 0 #F5F5F6; 
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    min-width: 400px;
    width:auto;
    font-size:12px;
    height:200px;

    white-space:nowrap;

}

#calcTextArea { 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-left:21%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: @user3682802 check the update. Accidentally posted other code

Comment: For the live demo? The live demo isn't the behavior I'm after. :/

Comment: That is the behavior but the fact you have to begin typing at that padding is not what I'm looking for. Plus, everything is not aligned. The title is off center.

Comment: @user3682802 you can make those changes to Amir's demo by 1)removing 'padding-left:21%;' from #calcTextArea, 2) adding 'text-align: center;' to #solWrap, and 3) adding 'text-align: left;' to #solTitles and #solStats in the CSS.

Comment: You do that though and you lose the behavior I originally wanted... :/

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div id="solWrap" class='parentDiv'>    
 ....Child divs
```

css

```
 .parentDiv { 
 width: 100%;
 text-align:center;


 }

.chilDiv {
width: 90%;
text-align:left;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: Please also provide an explanation of the code to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if I'm way off here but why can't you use a table?

```
<table id="stats_table">
    <tbody id="stats_table_body">
        <tr>
            <td class="title">Sample Variance:</td>
            <td class="value">12.212</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title">Population Variace:</td>
            <td class="value">12.291</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you need to create though javascript:

```
var myStats = [{title: 'Sample Variance', value: 12.212},
               {title: 'Population Variace', value: 12.291}];
function makeStatsTable(stats){
    var table = document.getElementById("stats_table_body");

    stats.forEach(function(stat){
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");

        var title = document.createElement("td");
        title.className = "title";
        title.textContent = stat.title;
        tr.appendChild( title );

        var value = document.createElement("td");
        value.className = "value";
        value.textContent = stat.value;
        tr.appendChild( value );

        table.appendChild( tr );
    });
}

makeStatsTable( myStats );
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xiondark2008/8X7MZ/

Comment: It would create too much of an issue trying to insert the data into the table with JavaScript with a possibility it displays the same behavior as divs. Plus, you hardcoded with width of both columns into your css, which is something I am unable (or unwilling) to do.

Comment: @user3682802 The css is where the hard coded widths came from. If you delete all the css, since it is not needed, the width of the columns will be dependent on the longest value in the column. Granted this still means using a table, so it might not solve anything.

Comment: Yea, I know, but I'd rather just not have the functionality than deal with inserting into a table. Plus, the calculator is going into a WordPress blog the table will inherit things that I probably wouldn't want, but the div won't. Thanks, anyways.